# Mapping an element from a set X to a pair of elements from a set Y through a property

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A software iterates over existing set of objects $X$ and for each element $x \in X$ creates two elements (non-existing by now objects) in the co-domain $Y$. The index relation is such, as element $x_{k} \in X$ is related to (or causes the creation of) elements $y_{2k} \in Y$ and $y_{2k+1} \in Y$. The relation between the objects (elements of $X$ and $Y$) is through their "name" properties, which is $y_{2k}.name=x_{k}.name$ and $y_{2k+1}.name=concat(somestr,x_{k}.name)$. 
**somestr** is a string constant pre-pended to the name of the second created object.

I would like to express this case mathematically.

Comment: Will $f(x)$ be an ordered or unordered pair?

Comment: an unordered pair

Comment: There is not even a commonly understood notation for the set of all unordered pairs of elements of $Y$. I've seen both $\binom Y2$ and $\mathcal P_2(Y)$ being used but either of them will need to be explained explicitly to your readership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not correct nor would it be understandable without your statement of what you mean to indicate by it. (Whatever is $Y'$?) Since I posted a first answer, you clarified the question. So, you want the values to be *unordered* pairs of elements of $Y$. You'll need a notation for that — let's use $\mathcal{P}_2(Y)$. If $Y$ has $n$ elements then $\mathcal{P}_2(Y)$ has $\binom{n}{2} = \frac {n(n-1)}{2}$ elements.

You could write your function as
$$
f\colon x \mapsto \{y, y'\}\colon X \to \mathcal{P}_2(Y). \tag{*}
$$
Thus for $x\in X$, $f(x) = \{y,y'\}$ is in $\mathcal{P}_2(Y)$, so $y, y' \in Y$.

There are other, more conversational ways to express it, but sticking to symbols, (*) is a common one. Some authors reverse the order of the parts that follow colons, and would instead write
$$
f\colon X \to \mathcal{P}_2(Y) \colon x \mapsto \{y,y'\}.
$$
It's a little "funny" for the expression following $\mapsto$ to not involve the variable or expression preceding it. It might be less odd to indicate the dependency on $x$ in the members of the value, as in "$x\mapsto \{y_x, y_x'\}$".

Note that values of $f$ have two distinct elements: if $f(x) = \{y,y'\}$ then $y\ne y'$, as elements of $\mathcal{P}_2(Y)$ have size $2$. If you want to allow $y=y'$, you have to change the range to $\mathcal{P}_1(Y) \cup \mathcal{P}_2(Y)$, where $\mathcal{P}_1(Y) = \big\{\{y\}\mid y\in Y\big\}$.

Judging from your diagram, you probably want the values to be true pairs, not degenerate ones (singletons). The function shown in the diagram has a stronger property, which you didn't mention in your question so I assumed wasn't essential. However, you do allude to it in a comment, when you ask about the size relationship between $X$ and $Y$. Specifically, the diagrammed function has the property that *$f$ is an injection and its range is a partition of $Y$*:

1. for $x_1, x_2\in X$, if $x_1\ne x_2$ then $f(x_1)\cap f(x_2)=\emptyset$, and
2. $\bigcup_{x\in X} f(x) = Y$.

If this is actually what you require then of course you'll have to say so, pretty much as above. And yes, in this case, if $\lvert X\rvert = n$ then $\lvert Y\rvert = 2n$.

---

*(After discussion in comments)* It's helpful to identify the two functions that take $x\in X$ to the $y, y'\in Y$ to which it gives rise. This association is indirect, via "name" mappings from $X$ and $Y$ into some set of strings $S$ — the set of all strings, or all strings meeting some criterion:
$$\begin{align}
&name_X\colon X \stackrel{1-1}{\longrightarrow} S, \\
&name_Y\colon Y \stackrel{1-1}{\longrightarrow} S. \\
\end{align}$$
Because these are 1-1, they have inverses that are partial functions on $S$, for example $name_X^{-1}$.

it seems that in software, this function $f$ not only has the properties already discussed, but also is a factory: its implementation actually constructs objects with names derived from that of its argument — something like this, where $\mathtt{pre}$ is some string constant:
$$
\mathtt{f}\colon x \mapsto \{\mathtt{Y}(name_X(x)), \mathtt{Y}( \mathtt{pre} + name_X(x) )\}
$$
Here, "$+$" is concatenation, and $\mathtt{Y}(\nu)$ constructs a $Y$ object with name $\nu$, presumably unique for $Y$s.

Finally, here are those functions that take an $X$ to its progeny in $Y$:
$$\begin{align}
x &\mapsto name_Y^{-1}(name_X(x)), \\
x &\mapsto name_Y^{-1}( \mathtt{pre} + name_X(x) ). \\
\end{align}$$

The first of these is $name_Y^{-1} \circ name_X$; the second is $name_Y^{-1} \circ [\nu \mapsto \mathtt{pre} + \nu]  \circ name_X$.

Comment: Does $Y \times Y$ mean "any combination" of the elements of Y?

Comment: Note that this doesn't make the values of $f$ _unordered_ pairs (like the OP explained he wanted shortly after this answer was posted).

Comment: What is the size of Y for X with 5 elements for example?

Comment: Shortly speaking, I am afraid, that $Y \times Y$ is a set of a size $N^{2}$ and I am asking about a resulting co-domain with a size of $2N$, where $N$ is the size of $X$, hence I am still not convinced, that those notations are the right ones for my particular case.

Comment: I have updated the question to make it (I hope) more clear

Comment: @scopchanov It's clearER now. I altered my answer to reflect your change. Re your question, "What is the size of $Y$ for $X$ with $5$ elements, for example?" -- from what you've said, $Y$ has nothing whatsoever to do with $X$ so the question can't be answered. If $Y$ has, say, $N$ elements, then $\mathcal{P}_2(Y)$ has $\binom{N} {2} = N(N-1)/2$ elements. If $N = 5$ then that number happens to equal $2N$ but that's an accident not the general rule.

Comment: The goal of the notation I am looking for is to give a formal description of the algorithm for creating two objects out of one in a computer program. Because these objects do not have single numerical values, but a list of properties, the expression following $\mapsto$ does not involve directly the expression preceding it. The relation between the objects (elements of $X$ and $Y$) is through their "name" properties, which is $y^{\prime}_{2k}.name = x_{k}.name$ and $y^{\prime}_{2k+1}.name = concat(somestr, x_{k}.name)$. Could You provide me with a suitable notation for this particular problem.

Comment: @scopchanov OK that's interesting. The *name*s are unique, yes? Obviously not every object designated by a legal *name* exists; the objs get created at some point. It sounds like the software realizing this function is a factory. How large is $Y$? Small enough to simply create all the $Y$s? ... IF you're mapping to existing elements, and if I understood what you intend by $somestr$ correctly, then in words, the function is: "$x \mapsto$ the unique $\{y,y'\}$ such that [$y.name = x.name$ and $y'.name$ ends with $x.name$]" <cont>...

Comment: ...<cont> Mathematically, "$o\mapsto o.name$" is two functions: $name_X\colon X\to S$ and $name_Y\colon Y\to S$, with $S =$ all strings, or all strings with some chosen structure. <2/3> ...

Comment: ...<3/3> The other reading is that $somestr$ is some particular string, something from... outer scope? That is, is the software function actually more like this? —
$$
(x, somestr) \mapsto \{ get_Y(name), get_Y(somestr + name)\}
$$
Here $get_Y(string)$ is a bijection, mapping a string name to the unique  $Y$ that it designates. In software, $get_Y$ might *memoize* the $\nu\mapsto name_Y^{-1}(v)$ mapping: if $get_Y$ hasn't seen the name $\nu$ before then it constructs a $Y$ with that name, just in time, and returns *that*. In database usage, this operation is called "upsert", not "get".

Comment: The software iterates over existing set of objects $X$ and for each element $x \in X$ creates two elements (non-existing by now objects) in the co-domain $Y$. I think we are getting pretty close to what I need (and thanks for helping me with that). Still, I am missing the index relation, namely element $x_{k} \in X$ is related (or causes the creation) of elements $y_{2k} \in Y$ and $y_{2k+1} \in Y$. I've used $Y^{\prime}$ to designate that the newly created objects form a two-objects-set in $Y$. As for <somestr>, it is just a string constant pre-pended to the name of the second created object.

Comment: The "index relation" is two functions:
$$\begin{align}
x &\mapsto name_Y^{-1}(name_X(x)) \\
x &\mapsto name_Y^{-1}( concat(\mathtt{prefix}, name_X(x)) ) \\
\end{align}$$
The first is $name_Y^{-1} \circ name_X$.

Comment: This looks like what I need. Please, add it as an answer and I will mark it as one. I will update my question with the additional details in order to help future readers understand the problem/solution. Thank You very much for Your kind help!

Comment: And one last question. Could You please explain me the meaning of -1 in the upper index?

Comment: I mean I know it is the inverse function, but how it should be understood in this case.

Comment: Exactly, it's the inverse function. $name_X^{-1}$ takes $X$s to their names, $name_X^{-1}$ takes names to $X$s. The inverses are presumably partial functions, not defined for all names.

Comment: Very good solution and explanation! Thank You very much for the time and efforts spent on that topic! If You intend to write a scientific paper on this issue I would be glad to cite it.

Comment: Thanks, and you're welcome. To merit a paper, perhaps a more general result...

Comment: Probably generalizing upon any number of produced elements in $Y$ from one side and mapping through any property of $X$ from another will be a good direction.

Comment: I will post this as a new question, since it is a new problem.

Comment: OK, post a comment here with a link when you do.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1762085/set-relations-through-the-properties-of-their-elements